# How do I setup a live trading view chart with custom UDF datafeed?

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

I am trying to use the javascript Trading View charting library to display my live equity data. I setup a rest api endpoint that gets historical equity data every one minute. I tried to format it with UDF but not sure if it's correct. I'm trying to build a line chart that displays the equity history + new data every one minute without a page refresh. Here is the javascript code:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
                name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
                var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
                    results = regex.exec(location.search);
                return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }

            function initOnReady() {
                var proxyServerUrl = "https://example.herokuapp.com/"
                var apiEndpointUrl = "https://api.example.com/endpoint";
                var datafeedUrl = proxyServerUrl + apiEndpointUrl;
                
                var customDataUrl = getParameterByName('dataUrl');
                if (customDataUrl !== "") {
                    datafeedUrl = customDataUrl.startsWith('https://') ? customDataUrl : `https://${customDataUrl}`;
                }

                var widget = window.tvWidget = new TradingView.widget({
                    // debug: true, // uncomment this line to see Library errors and warnings in the console
                    fullscreen: true,
                    interval: '1m',
                    container: "tv_chart_container",

                    //  BEWARE: no trailing slash is expected in feed URL
                    datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed(datafeedUrl),
                    library_path: "charting_library/",
                    locale: getParameterByName('lang') || "en",

                    disabled_features: ["use_localstorage_for_settings"],
                    enabled_features: ["study_templates"],
                    charts_storage_url: 'https://saveload.tradingview.com',
                    charts_storage_api_version: "1.1",
                    client_id: 'tradingview.com',
                    user_id: 'public_user_id',
                    theme: getParameterByName('theme'),
                });
            };

            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initOnReady, false);
```

I use my custom rest API endpoint and make a GET request to retrieve the UDF datafeed. Here is the format of the response:

```
{'statusCode': 200,
 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
 'body': '{"s": "ok", "t": [1675990743000, 1675990802000, 1675990863000], "c": [233899.0, 233717.0, 233427.0]}'}
```

I tried to run this script but the chart did not load and I got these error messages in the console.

```
Uncaught Error: Symbol is not defined: either 'symbol' or 'load_last_chart' option must be set

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsupported datafeed configuration. Must either support search, or support group request
    at e.UDFCompatibleDatafeed._setupWithConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "Symbol is not defined" suggests that you need to specify a symbol for the chart. You can do this by adding the following line to your widget configuration:

symbol: 'AAPL',

The error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" indicates that the server is returning a 403 Forbidden response, which means that the client is not authorized to access the requested resource. You need to check the server logs or contact the server administrator to see why this is happening.

The error "Unsupported datafeed configuration" suggests that the data feed you're using doesn't meet the required specifications. TradingView's UDF protocol requires either the search or the group endpoint to be present. Make sure your endpoint implements either of these endpoints and returns the data in the correct format. You can refer to the UDF documentation for more information on the required data format: https://www.tradingview.com/developers/docs/data-feed/